# How to fade out div after a few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to show a div when you click another one. But now I want the div to fade out automatically after a few seconds. 
I can't seem to find out the code I need to add...

```
function Show_Div(card) {
    if (false == $(card).is(':visible')) {
        $(card).fadeIn(250);
    }
    else {
        $(card).fadeOut(250);
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me out!

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your requirement correctly, then following spinet of code is solution for your requirement.

```
function Show_Div(card) {
    if (false == $(card).is(':visible')) {
        $(card).fadeIn(250);
        setTimeout(function(){ $(card).fadeOut() }, 5000);
    }
    else {
        $(card).fadeOut(250);
    }
}
```

> Note: 5000(5 seconds) is the time after which the div will fadeout.
>
> Edit: card is a variable so removed the single quotes

Answer (score 2):

Use `setTimeout`:

```
function Show_Div(card) {
    if (false == $(card).is(':visible')) {
        $(card).fadeIn(250);
        setTimeout(function(){
             $(card).fadeOut(250);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        $(card).fadeOut(250);
    }
}
```

1000 is one second

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout would do the trick.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

```
function Show_Div(card) {
if (false == $(card).is(':visible')) {
    $(card).fadeIn(250);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(card).fadeOut(250); }, 3000);
}
else {
    $(card).fadeOut(250);
}
```

}

Comment: You should use `===` for exact comparison